# select the first 5 records in a particular order for each foreign key

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with three columns

```
fk_id,
sort_column,
value_column
```

for each fk__id_  I'd like to retrieve the first 5 records order by the sort_column

I've tried this for several hours now and I don't have the slightest idea on how to do it

I'm using MySQL

I'd be grateful for any help

Marc

EDIT:
I should probably clarify the output format I'm looking for:
I want two columns, fk id and value_column
fk id would just be repeated 5 times for each value

the reason I wanna do this is because later on I need to do some calculations on this results set such as calculating the average and the sum for each fk_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this code](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/) and then add `AND row_number < 5`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done.
You would probably have to use a scripting language to do this individually for each fk_id

I could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you're looking for.

```
SELECT t1.fk_id, t1.value_column
FROM table AS t1
LEFT JOIN table AS t2
    ON t1.fk_id=t2.fk_id AND t1.sort_column < t2.sort_column
WHERE t2.fk_id IS NULL
ORDER BY t1.sort_column DESC
LIMIT 5
```